# Vite Serve and Build at the same time

Tags: vue.js, vite

I have an unusual case where I need to serve my Vue app in two ways simultaneously:

- as a normal dev server index file with HMR, usually achieved using `vite serve`
- as built files used in a separate app, build on file change using `vite build --watch`

This is because we are transitioning a classic server side rendered site to use Vue, but want to convert sections of the site to Vue one byu one over time. We are importing the built folders manually and conditionally rendering components as pages: however we still want to work on the full SPA app rebuild, and test pages in the new SPA as well as the old site.

I can find plenty of documentation for using either build mode but not both at the same time.

Comment: Simply run two different command line terminals at the same time.  `serve` on one, `build --watch` on the other.

Comment: my issue is that I have dockerised my development environment, so I'm limited to a single process per container. I'm looking for a solution that will let me combine the above so I can run both from one location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, for sure you can runn commands simultaneously, but not in vite. you need another npm module:

```
npm install --save-dev npm-run-all
```

Then, update your `package.json` file:

```
"scripts": {
  "serve": "vite serve",
  "watch": "vite build --watch",
  "dev": "run-p serve watch"
}
```

so, by running `npm run dev`, both `serve` and `watch` run simultaneously.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is exactly what I was after, thanks!